# truncate absolute path in archive

Tags: linux, zip

In my script, I call the `zip`-command with the full path of the archive and the target directory like so:

```
zip -r /srv/www/htdocs/xxx/system/tmp/build/tmp_build.zip /srv/www/htdocs/xxx/system/tmp/build/tmp_build_dir_1344856484/
```

The `tmp_build_dir_1344856484`-directory tree looks as follows:

```
+
|-- output.xml
|-+ ressources/
  |- some_file.png
  |- another_file.png
```

My problem now is, that I need the root of the zip-archive to have the XML file and the `ressources`-folder, but currently, the archive also includes the full path name.

```
# Wanted path to some_file.png in zip-file:
/ressources/some_file.png
# What I currently get:
/srv/www/htdocs/xxx/system/tmp/build/tmp_build_dir_1344856484/ressources/some_file.png
```

How can I truncate the path just to a certain level so I can keep the sub-folder but not have the whole directory tree in it?

Comment: I ended up changing the work-directory like explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/825322/717341)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ cd /srv/www/htdocs/xxx/system/tmp/build/tmp_build_dir_1344856484/
$ zip -r ../tmp_build.zip .
```

Comment: It's probably better to use a subshell in scripts to do not modify current working directory, like `(cd $long_path && zip -r ../tmp_build.zip)`. Or one also can use `pushd/popd` for that.